# How to rotate a pixmap by 90º to draw to a texture in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, pixmap

I need to rotate a Pixmap by 90 degrees. I have seen an answer that achieves a f[lipped Pixmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19746741/2399024). I need to rotate images that are in portrait orientation to landscape already on the Pixmap-level to later create textures out of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

similar to the [flip pixmap method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19746741/2399024) I achieved a 90º rotated Pixmap like this:

```
private Pixmap rotatePixmap (Pixmap srcPix){
    final int width = srcPix.getWidth();
    final int height = srcPix.getHeight();
    Pixmap rotatedPix = new Pixmap(height, width, srcPix.getFormat());

    for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
            rotatedPix.drawPixel(x, y, srcPix.getPixel(y, x));
        }
    }

    srcPix.dispose();
    return rotatedPix;
}
```

Note that also width & height get swapped after the 90º rotation